# PHP comparing string date values are outputting different outputs

Tags: php

Why don't both $date_1 and $date_2 both output the same echo statement since they are both greater than $date_3?

```
<?php

$date_1 = "03-10-2021";
$date_2 = "04-13-2021";

$date_3 = "02-18-2020";

$dateTimestamp1 = strtotime($date_1);
$dateTimestamp2 = strtotime($date_2);
$dateTimestamp3 = strtotime($date_3);

if ($dateTimestamp1 > $dateTimestamp3){   
    echo "$date_1 comes after $date_3";
} else {    
    echo "$date_1 comes before $date_3";
}

echo(PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL);

if ($dateTimestamp2 > $dateTimestamp3){   
    echo "$date_2 comes after $date_3";
} else {    
    echo "$date_2 comes before $date_3";
}
?>
```

output:

03-10-2021 comes after 02-18-2020

04-13-2021 comes before 02-18-2020

Comment: Because both `$dateTimestamp2` and `dateTimestamp3` hold the value false thus `$dateTimestamp2 > $dateTimestamp3` evaluates to false as well. [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-description)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of magic in `strtotime($date_1)`. Use `(DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y',$date_1)) -> getTimestamp()` with explicit format instead. The rest is your code and it works fine.

```php
<?php
$date_1 = "03-10-2021";
$date_2 = "04-13-2021";

$date_3 = "02-18-2020";

$dateTimestamp1 = (DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y',$date_1)) -> getTimestamp();
$dateTimestamp2 = (DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y',$date_2)) -> getTimestamp();
$dateTimestamp3 = (DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y',$date_3)) -> getTimestamp();

if ($dateTimestamp1 > $dateTimestamp3){   
    echo "$date_1 comes after $date_3";
} else {    
    echo "$date_1 comes before $date_3";
}

echo(PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL);

if ($dateTimestamp2 > $dateTimestamp3){   
    echo "$date_2 comes after $date_3";
} else {    
    echo "$date_2 comes before $date_3";
}
?>
```